# No transitions in jssor different size image slider

Tags: jssor

Page is here https://coloradophotographyschool.com/tvimages.php

Using jssor slider for images for different size. Now the transitions are gone, it just blanks out between slides. I've set $SlideshowOptions, and propagated _SlideshowTransitions, but nothing.

Can anyone see where I've broken something in the page source?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `background-color: black;` from your page.

In other words, replace

```
<style>
    html, body, div, img {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: black;
    }
</style>
```

with

```
<style>
    html, body, div, img {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
</style>
```